# Apply a command to specific files

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a bash script that take a command from user and apply it in specific type of files. 
Could somebody please provide the code.

```
echo "Enter your command"
read user-cm
echo "Enter the type of files (ex. php, c, )"
read filetp
find . -name "*. $filetp" -type f  | xargs $user-cm
```

ok i found just change the variable name of user-cm to something(mycm) and put xargs "$mycm"

```
echo "Enter your command"
read mycm
echo "Enter the type of files (ex. php, c, )"
read filetp
find  -name "*."$filetp"" -type f  | xargs "$mycm"
```

Comment: Mhhh !? Don't you provide it already ?

Comment: So why don't you explain that in your original POST and post errors ??? Be more specific !

Answer (score 1):

Just some few corrections :

```
echo "Enter your command"
read user_cm
echo "Enter the type of files (ex. php, c, )"
read filetp
find . -name "*.$filetp" -type f  | xargs $user_cm
```

You had a space in the find's name and `-` is not allowed in variables names.

When things 'doesn't work', check carefully errors messages, they are significant in general.

Comment: i get the same error as before line 2: read: `user-cm': not a valid identifier

Comment: i found the first problem, i change the variable name to mycm but a i get  another problem 
xargs: invalid option -- 'c'
Usage: xargs [-0prtx] [--interactive] [--null] [-d|--delimiter=delim]
       [-E eof-str] [-e[eof-str]]  [--eof[=eof-str]]

Comment: you forget to change last user_cm variable after xargs ?